# Coded UI Recording using Google Chrome

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Is it possible to record actions in Google chrome using Coded-U-I?
It is happening in Internet Explorer without any error but throws an exception while using chrome.

Comment: @JeroenJK The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties.

Comment: I am trying to record the Google search bar and also trying to parameterize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have all the [requirements and set up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx).

After that: when you use the UISpy crosshairs over the control, can you compare the list of search properties to see if they are in fact slightly different between the browsers? It might be possible to edit the list of search properties used to find the control by removing the differences, but outcomes vary.

Comment: And did you take a look at the properties for the control in the 2 different browsers?

Comment: Yes i tried doing that but the "text" property was read-only i.e. {get;}. So didn't help much.Thus tried the other way.